# Is a quotient of a locally compact separable metric space submetrisable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a quotient of a locally compact separable metric space $Y$. Is $X$ submetrisable (i.e. does $X$ have a coarser topology that is metrisable)?

Comment: Do you have any motivation for this problem, or similar results which lead you to think this is true ? Why the interest in submetrisable spaces?

Comment: Only that "submetrizable hemicompact k-space" brings up quite a few entries on google, and these seemed the most likely hemicompact k-spaces to be submetrizable. I have no intuition for submetrisabilty whatever.

Comment: hemicompact $k$-spaces suggests to me that you intend to work with $C_k(X)$ (like) spaces? (function spaces in the compact-open topology)

Comment: Not really. It is the underlying space that I am interested in. I suppose my real question is: how does one characterise the $k_{\omega}$-spaces that are quotients of locally compact separable metric spaces? I thought that submetrisabiltiy might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $X$ can fail to be even Hausdorff (for instance, if $Y$ is non-empty, $Z$ is a proper dense subset of $Y$, $x^\star\not\in Y\setminus Z$, $X=(Y\setminus Z)\cup \{ x^\star \}$, and $q:Y\to X$ be the quotient map such that $q(x)=x$ for each $x\in Y\setminus Z$ and $q(x)=x^\star $ for each $x\in Z$.

On the other hand, we have the following

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a $T_1$ and $T_3$ space, which is a continuous image of a space with a countable network. Then $X$ is submetrizable.

*Proof.* Since the space $X$ has a countable network, the space $X^2$ is hereditarily Lindelöf.

We claim that the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\in X^2\}$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of $X^2$. Indeed, let $(x,y)\in X^2\setminus\Delta$ be any point. Since $X^2$ is Hausdorff there exist open in $X$ disjoint neighborhoods $U_{(x,y)}$ and  $V_{(x,y)}$ of the points $x$ and $y$, respectively. Since the space $X$ is $T_3$, there exist open in $X$ disjoint neighborhoods $U’_{(x,y)}$ and $V’_{(x,y)}$ of the points $x$ and $y$, respectively such that $\overline{U’_{(x,y)}}\subset U_{(x,y)}$ and $\overline{V’_{(x,y)}}\subset V_{(x,y)}$. A family $$\{ U’_{(x,y)}\times V’_{(x,y)}:(x,y)\in X^2\setminus\Delta\}$$ is an open cover of the space $X^2\setminus \Delta$. Since the latter space is Lindelöf, there exists a countable subset $Z$ of $X^2\setminus\Delta$ such that a family $\{ U’_{z}\times V’_{z}:z\in Z\}$ is a cover of $X^2\setminus\Delta$. Then $\Delta=\bigcup_{z\in Z} X^2\setminus \overline{U’_{z}}\times \overline{V’_{z}}$.

Since the space $X$ is Lindelöf, by Theorem 3.8.11 from [Eng], it is paracompact. By Corollary 2.9 from [Gru] (see also [Bor] and [Oku]), $X$ is submetrizable.

**Theorem 3.8.11.** [Eng] Every open cover of a Lindelöf space has a locally finite open refinement.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of a Lindelöf space $X$. The space $X$ being regular, for every $x\in X$ there exist open sets $U_x,V_x\subset X$ such that $x\in U_x\subset\overline{U_x}\subset V_x$ and $V_x$ is contained in a member of $\mathcal U$. Let $\{U_{x_i}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a countable subcover of the cover $\{U_x\}_x\in X$ of
the space $X$. The sets $$W_i = V_{x_i}\setminus \left(U_{x_1}\cup U_{x_2}\cup\dots U_{x_{i-1}}\right),\mbox{ where }i = 1,2,\dots,$$ are open and constitute a cover of $X$. Indeed, for any $x\in X$ we have $x\in W_{i(x)}$ where $i(x)$ is the smallest integer $i$ satisfying $x\in V_{x_i}$. The cover $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is a refinement of $\mathcal U$ and is locally finite because $U_{x_j}\cap W_i=\varnothing$ for $i> j$. $\square$

*References*

[Bor] C.R. Borges, *On stratifiable spaces*, Pacific J. Math., **17**,  1–16.

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

[Gru] Gary Gruenhage *Generalized Metric Spaces*, in: K.Kunen, J.E.Vaughan (eds.) *Handbook of Set-theoretic
Topology*, Elsevier Science Publishers B.V., 1984.

[Oku] A. Okuyama, *On metrizability of $M$-spaces*, Proc. Japan Acad., **40**, 176–179.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had forgotten that there were also non-Hausdorff quotients. I will have to remind myself of the various definitions, like "countable network".

Comment: Thanks. So the spaces that I am interested in are "cosmic $k_{\omega}$-spaces" and they are all submetrisable.