# Is a submetrisable $k_{\omega}$-space a quotient of a locally compact separable metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

This question is a follow-on from [Is a quotient of a locally compact separable metric space submetrisable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861952/is-a-quotient-of-a-locally-compact-separable-metric-space-submetrisable)
and asks for the converse. In that question it was shown that a $k_{\omega}$-space is submetrisable if it is the quotient of a locally compact separable metric space.

Does the converse hold: that is, is a submetrisable $k_{\omega}$-space the quotient of a locally compact separable metric space?

(A $k_{\omega}$-space is a Hausdorff quotient of a locally compact $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space. A space is *submetrisable* if it has a coarser topology which is metrisable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Indeed, it can be shown that a *$k_\omega$-space* $X$ has a countable cover $\{K_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ by its compact subsets, determining the topology of $X$ in the sense that a subset $U$ of $X$ is open in $X$ if and only if the intersection $U\cap K_n$ is open in $K_n$ for any $n$.

If the space $X$ is submetrizable then each $K_n$ is submetrizable. Since it is compact, it admits no strictly weaker Hausdorff topology, so $K_n$ is a metrizable (and so second countable) compact.

Now let $Y=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} K_n\times \{n\}$ be a subspace of $X\times \Bbb N$. Then $Y$ is a locally compact Hausdorff second countable (and so metrizable) space and a projection of $Y$  onto its first factor is a quotient map onto $X$.

Comment: Many thanks once again.